# Is IdentityHashMap class wrong?

Tags: java

I tested with `java.util.IdentityHashMap`, See

```
public class IdentityHashMapTest{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, String> m = new IdentityHashMap<String, String>();
        m.put("John", "Doe");
        m.put("John", "Paul");
        System.out.println(m.size());
    }
}
```

According to Java API said,

> This class implements the Map interface with a hash table, using reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys (and values)

The result may be `2`. But actual is `1`. Is IdentityHashMap class wrong?

Comment: As `"John" == "John"` they are the same object so you have only one key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to

```
       m.put("John", "Doe");
       m.put(new String("John"), "Paul");
```

and it will have two entries. String literals are pooled, so `"John" == "John"`.

Answer (score 1):

`IdentityHashMap` violates the Map contracts and uses object identity to check key equality instead of `equals` method, since Strings are pooled its actually one object, you should use `new String("John")` to have new entry in Map.

Comment: TreeMap and ConcurrentSkipListMap don't use equals() either.

Comment: They violate in other way ;-) .. which is cleared in javadocs

Comment: `More generally, implementations of the various Collections Framework interfaces are free to take advantage of the specified behavior of underlying Object methods wherever the implementor deems it appropriate.` Appears to get an escape clause to avoid violation.

Comment: true but IdentityHashMap javadocs have mentioned this violation - `While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects.`

Comment: I note that TreeMap says `The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface.` Why Map mandates that equals be used when half the implementation don't is beyond me.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Different methods which take a `Map` parameter do different things with it.  Some of the things methods may do with a passed-in `Map` will only be useful with implementations that use `equals` in normal fashion, but some will be useful with other implementations.  The first and foremost goal of a programming language design should be to allow programmers to do things that are useful.  If some routines which take a `Map` could would behave usefully if given an `IdentityHashMap`, that's a pretty big argument in favor of allowing an `IdentityHashMap` to be passed to them.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that string literals are pooled.

You can test that `"John" == "John"` is true.

So the two keys you use are not only equal, they are identical.

Extract from the [JLS #3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5-410):

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals are "interned" so as to share unique instances.